# How do I make one column turn into an index and another a header with the 3 column being data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

initial code

```
num1  num2  num3  
0  A     a     1.1
1  A     b     1.3
2  A     c     .8
3  B     a     .4
4  B     b     1.2
5  B     c     2.1
```

I want it to be

```
   a    b    c
A  1.1  1.3  .8
B  .4   1.2  2.1
```

I tried df.set_index('num1') and df.set_index('num2').T but they didn't seem to get what I wanted.

Comment: have you looked at pivot/pibot_table?

Answer (score 0):

Use that:

```py
your_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='num3', index=['num1'],
                    columns=['num2'], fill_value=0)
```